# How long can php hold connection open and how to increase it?

Tags: ajax

I am using ajax long polling to create chat and after one minute of inactivity connection closes. What i need is to keep that connection open.  How do i fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot really answer, since you do not tell why the connection is closed. You will have to find out. It might be that you run into the time limit a php is granted, this is a php setting you could change. Those settings are well documented, also the configuration file itself (`php.ini`) contains valuable explanations.

Answer (score 0):

By default, php can run in 30 seconds, after 30s, if instructions have not complete, it will be interupted.
To increase execute time, update file php.ini, variable set_time_limit — Limits the maximum execution time. You can read references: [set_time_limit](http://www.php.net/set_time_limit)